# `routes.php` config example

Tags: config, routes

I want to move some permanent routes from the admin to my routes config file so that they can be version controlled.

```
in the admin...
news-sort/month/<year>/<month> ....
news-sort/tag/<tag> ....
news-sort/author/<*>
```

Do these look ok, not 100% sure on the variable and regex etc.

```
'news-sort/month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})' => 'news-sort/index',
'news-sort/tag/(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+)' => 'news-sort/index',
'news-sort/author/(?P<author>[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+)' => 'news-sort/index'
```

Comment: Do they work, mjr?

Comment: I tested one and it seems to work ok

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to transform [dynamic routes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) into [advanced routes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#advanced-routing), is to go to your `craft_routes` table and copy it out of `urlPattern`:

**Example:**

If you have set this in your backend:
`news-sort/month/<year>/<month>`

You'll find this in `urlPattern`:
`news\-sort\/month\/(?P<year>\d{4})\/(?P<month>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012]))`

Just remove the escaping `\`, and you've got your regex:
`news-sort/month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012]))`

Comment: great idea, I never thought of that!

Comment: awesome answer!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to escape the dot, but otherwise it looks good to me.

You could replace `[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]` with `.` to allow all characters in the slug. Maybe you want to use german umlauts or other special characters in your slugs at some point (you probably shouldn't, but who knows). I'd do that (the `.`, not the umlauts), as I think it's not the task of a route to restrict you in doing such things.